# Sorting in Jekyll / liquid code based on two columns

Tags: sorting, markdown, jekyll, liquid

In my code  I am trying to read about 100 yml files and create an html table. The problem I am facing is I am unable to sort based on two columns. The column names are vendor and name.
I need to first sort on Vendor and then name.

It sorts on one columns only the vendor column and ignore the next column name.. All the column names are correct.

This is the code.

```
         {% assign devices = "" | split: " " %}
         {% for device in site.data.devices %}
         {% assign devices = devices | push: device[1] %}
         {% endfor %}

         {% assign sorted = devices | sort_natural: 'name' | sort_natural: 'vendor' %}
         {% assign lastVendor = "" %}
         {% assign nbDevices = 0 %}

         {%- for device in sorted %}
         {%- assign nbDevices = nbDevices | plus:'1' %}
         {%- assign lastVendor = device.vendor %}` 
Here i start creating the table which gets filled with values from the yml files.
```

The table when created is sorted on only one column. Either vendor or name.

Tried `group_by` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651759/is-there-a-way-to-sort-lists-in-jekyll-by-two-fields) but then no values show up in the table not sure why.

Tried sort and sort_natural both the effect is the same.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out why the code was not working.

We were building our jekyll site using docker. The docker image was outdated.
A build using just `bundle exec jekyll serve` resolved the issue !!
Now need to update the bundler and gems....still figuring out what all gets updated and will post here in case it helps anyone.